# Apache forward request from port 80 to port 8000 based on url

Tags: apache

I have a rails application running in apache on port `8000` and some PHP applications running on port 80. Now I'm accessing my rails application by giving port 8000 in the URL (like `example.com/dashboard:8000`).

I would like to access my rails application also without the port in the URL. So in apache I want to write a condition to check for url with `/dashboard` and forward those requests to port `8000`.

I cannot use sub-domains, so it has to be based on URL.

I've searched around and saw that we can use **RewriteEngine** for conditions on URL, but I'm not able to figure out exactly how to do it, and I'm new to apache configurations, so could someone please help me with it.

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to use [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) to proxy the entire `/dashboard` subtree:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass        /dashboard http://localhost:8000/dashboard
ProxyPassReverse /dashboard http://localhost:8000/dashboard
```

but be aware that your rails application needs to know that it probably  shouldn't put the port number into the links, skyesheet refs, etc. it generates anymore.

Comment: @anirudh: is your rails thing configured to bind also to localhost or just to your public IP? (You can put your `example.com` in place of `localhost` if your app is not visible on localhost; personally, I prefer that my application servers are only visible on localhost, so all access control can be done by httpd, but that's a further step.)